# Problem uploading files from Mac

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, file-upload

A couple users has reported that they are having issues uploading files to a SharePoint Document Library. Both of them are using Mac.

- I have had both of them try Chrome and Safari to ensure it is not a browser issue.
- Tried multiple files.
- Attempted upload in multiple libraries.
- Ensured both users had Edit permissions in both libraries
- Had them try the drag and drop method and the click "New Document" method. Same results.
- Windows machines can upload to these same document libraries and files with no issues.

When they attempt to upload the files, they get the same thing - a spinning wheel when trying to upload. It just keeps spinning - there is no error message or anything.

We are using SharePoint Server 2013

I am not really sure where else to look at. Can anyone give me some advice ,I know nothing about Mac.

Comment: ugh that spinny beachball . Did you check for javaScript errors in the Browser's console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleageue ([Peter Reavy](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/48647/peter-reavy)) and I have been dealing with the same issue. We're also using SharePoint 2013 (on-premises, fully patched), and have replicated this error with a Mac laptop upgraded to macOS Sierra 10.12.1. We suspect this is a breaking change that has been introduced in either 10.12 (released at end of September) or more likely 10.12.1 (released at the end of October), as our users have only started reporting this error in the last week or so. Our current work-around is to ask users to use an alternative browser (Chrome or Firefox) when using a Mac.

As far as we can tell, the postback request on attempting to upload the file is hanging, with no network request(s) or errors being logged in the web developer tools for Safari.

I've [tweeted](https://twitter.com/AndyParkhill/status/802171210159243264) Stefan Gossner to ask if he (and Microsoft) are aware of this issue. I'll update this answer with any further details.

Comment: Thanks - Looks like you may have got a reply. Keep me updated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the File > Upload document option. New Document doesn't work. You'll be able to browser for the document you want to upload. However, the next screen that verifies you want to upload the document will show blank. Just hit "enter". Your document should then be uploaded. Refresh your browser to check. It would be nice if Microsoft made their tools work the same on a Mac as it does on a PC... but don't get me started!